# Will apple reject the app if we do not use Twitter framework for ios 5?

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter, ios4, uiwebview

In my app I've used twitter status update using share kit, but for iOS 5 i am not using Twitter framework.
authenticating user same as older iOS using webview.

Will apple reject my application?

Comment: I can't see why they would unless theres something specifically written into the T&C or dev rules.  Have you checked?  After all they like the idea of keeping the user experience the same whatever the platform, so being made to change the way your app works would seem a little silly.

Comment: @JonTaylor i thought so, thanks for replay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an iOS 5 app that doesn't, and because I haven't read anything from Apple about the Twitter framework becoming mandatory (which would be a big deal since many apps are still not using it) I believe your app will be approved without it.